# Latest nginx source on debian wheezy

Tags: linux, nginx, debian

In tutorials I have seen people talk about adding a source.list to get the latest nginx version. I found this one for debian 6:

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ squeeze nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ squeeze nginx
```

Can anyone tell me what it is for debain 7 please? I can't seem to find it, and I am not sure if exists yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this :

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ wheezy nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ wheezy nginx
```

Because the name of Debian 7 is "Wheezy".

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. browse the development source tree at http://hg.nginx.org/nginx/file/
2. or clone that reposity to your local machine by `hg clone http://hg.nginx.org/nginx`